# TestNG parametrized tests - unexpected dependency between tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I recently started learning Java (I am .net guy) and I have problem with the following unit test:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "rotatedArray")
public void given_array_of_items_rotates_array(Integer[] originalArray, int rotationCount, Integer[] expectedArray) {
    originalArray = originalArray.clone();

    Utils.rotate(originalArray, rotationCount);

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedArray, originalArray);
}

@DataProvider(name = "rotatedArray")
public static Object[][] rotatedArrayProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
            // array that is not rotated
            {
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    0,
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
            },

            // array rotated one place forward
            {
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    1,
                    new Integer[] { 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
            },

            // array rotated one place backward
            {
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    -1,
                    new Integer[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 }
            },

            // array rotated by array.length
            {
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    6,
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
            },

            // array rotated by array.length - 1
            {
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    5,
                    new Integer[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 }
            },

            // array rotated by some number of places backwards
            {
                    new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    -3,
                    new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3 }
            },
    };
}
```

`Utils.rotate` is simple function that rotates array passed as parameter by given number of positions. When I run this code in IntelliJ with commented line:

```
// originalArray = originalArray.clone();
```

two of `given_array_of_items_rotates_array` test cases fail without any meaningful message. Problem disappears when I uncomment line that clones array or when I reduce number of test cases in data provider. This test is only one that uses `rotatedArray` provider. It looks like problem lies in modifying input parameters - I searched TestNG documentation but I cannot find any clues.

EDIT:
After changing test method to:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "rotatedArray")
public void given_array_of_items_rotates_array(Integer[] originalArray, int rotationCount, Integer[] expectedArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++)
            originalArray[i] = 123;
}
```

some tests still doesn't pass. There is no output in the console.
It looks like it is problem with modification of parameters than with assertions.

IntelliJ:
[image: intellij_testresults_window]

Comment: Is an AssertionError thrown for the failed tests or something else? Please provide console output.

Answer (score 0):

Currently TestNG (6.9.9) may have some problems with arrays assertions. It should be fixed in the next release.
See https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/870